# st_intersects on postgis

Tags: postgis, intersection

I'm trying to write a command to see whether a given point lies within a multipolygon boundary (in this case, a watershed). I have a table of watershed boundaries and another table with the point I'm going to use to see which watershed the point lies in.

Would  [`st_intersects`](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Intersects.html)  be the correct command to run? (if so, how would I do that?). If not, what would be the best command to use?

I'm new to postgis/postgresql so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here are what the tables look like:

**Table A has point data:**

[image]

**Table H has polygons:**
 [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you're asking:

```
SELECT a.name, h.name
 FROM a5 a, HUC8 h
 WHERE ST_Intersects(a.the_geom, h.the_geom);
```